# ASP.net & MVC : AJAX & update PartialView & confirmation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, confirmation, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm using ASP.Net MVC to make my app

I'm actually trying to delete an entry from my DB, first i must have a confirmation message and when the action is completed i want to refresh my PartialView

here's my code

```
          <%= Ajax.ActionLink(
            "Supprimer", 
            "Delete", 
            "Users",
            new { item.ID },
            new AjaxOptions {
              Confirm= "confirmMethod",
              UpdateTargetId = "usersListeID",
              OnSuccess = "success"
           }
              )%>
```

The problem is the confirm option is a simple ajax message, i want to use my own message (well structured because I used ajax & jQuery to make it)

```
function confirmMethod() {
$.msgBox({
    title: "Demande de confirmation",
    content: "Voulez-vous effectuer cette action?",
    type: "confirm",
    buttons: [{ value: "Oui" }, { value: "Non"}],
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == "Non") {
            abort();
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: What is a "simple ajax message?"

Comment: @Andrey You can use jQuery dialog. Try this link http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a standard `Html.ActionLink`:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Supprimer", 
    "Delete", 
    "Users",
    new { item.ID },
    new { @class = "delete" }
) %>
```

and then use jQuery to subscribe to the `.click()` event of tis anchor:

```
$(function() {
    $('.delete').click(function() {
        var anchor = this;
        // Show the confirmation dialog
        $.msgBox({
            title: "Demande de confirmation",
            content: "Voulez-vous effectuer cette action?",
            type: "confirm",
            buttons: [{ value: "Oui" }, { value: "Non"}],
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Oui") {
                    // send the AJAX request if the user selected "Oui":
                    $.ajax({
                        url: anchor.href,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data) {
                            // When the AJAX request succeeds update the 
                            // corresponding element in your DOM
                            $('#usersListeID').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        // Always cancel the default action of the link
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but this solution updates the entire page, i want to update only my partial view (which ID is #usersListeID)

Comment: That's what the code I have shown does. If the AJAX call succeeds it updates the `#usersListeID` element with the content returned by your `Delete` action. So make sure that this action returns only the partial HTML you want to be updated and not an entire view.